# .on() mouseenter event works but click doesnt work jquery 2

Tags: jquery, event-delegation

My mind is boggled.  Can anyone tell me why this works with 'mouseenter' but not with 'click'?

http://jsfiddle.net/jxUGw/3/

```
//////THIS DOESNT WORK
$('#view_panel').on('click', 'img.main_image', function(){
    $(this).parent().find('div.image_box').show();
});

$('#view_panel').on('click', 'img.main_image', function(){
    $(this).parent().find('div.image_box').hide();
});


/////THIS WORKS
$('#view_panel').on('mouseenter', 'img.main_image', function(){
    $(this).parent().find('div.image_box').show();
});

$('#view_panel').on('mouseleave', 'img.main_image', function(){
    $(this).parent().find('div.image_box').hide();
});
```

Comment: You're assigning two click events, the first which shows your image box and a second that hides it. They are probably happening so quickly that it appears to not be working. You should change it to be a single click event that toggles visibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second event being bound is firing immediately after the first one. So the div is being hidden as soon it is shown.

Try using `toggle()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is not that it's not working, you just call both function when you click.

Try that instead (1 click function):

```
$('#view_panel').on('click', 'img.main_image', function(){
    $(this).parent().find('div.image_box').toggle();
});
```